# EF 6 - Executing function with return type in RAW Sql

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework

in our existing Oracle Database, we have a function with passing arguments which returns a number.

MyFunction(myParams) => returns "number"

In an Oracle-Environment, you can work with this method to execute and display the results.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF

DECLARE

vResult NUMBER;

BEGIN

vResult:= MyFunction(myParams);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vResult);

END;
```

How do i manage it in my EF 6 with raw sql-queries?
I thought about this approach, but i don't get the result i would like to.

```
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery(typeof(int),$@"<here the query>").ToListAsync();

// Trying the above sql-statement in the defined query works somehow, but doesnt return an integer / number.
```

What is the correct way to execute a function with a raw sql statement in an EF environment and getting the correct return value?

Kind regards

Comment: `db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("your query").First()` doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately not: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.'

Comment: So this suggests your query returns multiple columns, not just one (with number).

Comment: In my query, I excluded

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF

If my type is e.g. a List<string>, the result is empty (no entries).